# Magento routes - removing the default 'index' route from path

Tags: magento, routes

While building a custom magento module I'm finding the following:

xxx/view/id/4 = 404s
xxx/index/view/id4 = Routes properly

Is there a way to remove the initial index from the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Magento URL matching assumes at least three parts:

```
site.com/catalog/product/view/id/4  <--- params
           ^        ^     ^
           |        |     `----------- action
frontname--´        |
              controller path
```

Index is assumed. You can easily make a `ViewController` and use an `indexAction()` like your current `IndexController::viewAction()`. Repeat the pattern.

There are several other possibilities, including rewrites, custom router class, etc.

Comment: Makes sense :) Just was wondering if there was a cheeky method to doing it without using a specific controller!

Comment: I like how you dodged his question.  You said there are several possibilities but didn't explain how those were done lol.

Comment: Heh, yeah. I suppose answered OP's question (note the green check mark). I try to provide an answer with specificity which matches that of the original question; if OP needs more info, they can comment. @DuffyBelfield did, but I didn't answer because, well, he accepted. In his case I'd be inclined to use a custom router class. If you have a similar or related need, probably best to start a new question, and ping me at [@benmarks](http://twitter.com/benmarks) on the Twitters.